# Show Font Size & Weight next to Text inside the Flutter app

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Is there any way to present Font Size and Weight next to the text wherever available in the flutter app?

This approach is for testing the application to see if we used right font size and weight.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if what you are asking is possible or not. But if you want to keep your app consistent with respect to font size, you can add font sizes in the main.dart TextTheme section, and then use that size wherever you want to use it. You can declare multiple sizes for different kinds of texts.

See example here: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/themes

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Since our app consists of lot of text, we are looking for a way to achieve in program how do we show Font Size and Weight next to text in the app which will help to test the application. Later will remove this approach when app is live.